# How to format DOI in Rmd vignette so that correct in Rd?

Tags: r-markdown, r-package

When I check my package on rhub with devtools::check_rhub(), I get notes that there are incorrectly formatted DOIs in the vignettes, e.g.

> URL: doi:10.1029/2002GL016612
> From: inst/doc/introduction-to-sedproxy.html
> Message: Invalid URI scheme (use \doi for DOIs in Rd markup)

I am generating the vignettes from rmarkdown (.Rmd) files. How do I format DOIs in Rmd so that they will be correct in Rd?

Comment: I'll answer my own question in case someone else comes looking: https://doi.org/10.5194/cp-14-1851-2018 in plain text in the .Rmd works fine.

Answer (score 1):

From section `2.1.1 Documenting functions` in https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html :

`A section with references to the literature. Use \url{} or \href{}{} for web pointers, and \doi{} for DOIs (this needs R >= 3.3, see User-defined macros for more info).`

Thus, it's recommended to use this for your reference as well (even if it works directly without the `\doi{}` by prefixing it with the `https://doi.org/`):

`\doi{10.1029/2002GL016612}`

This should not prompt a NOTE from running `R CMD check` with `--as-cran`. This seems to be the case also for vignettes / R markdown and not just Rd files.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this and found that using Rmarkdown to insert a link added it in this form

```
[Pui](https://doi.org/10.1080/02786828708959166)
```

This works locally anyway. I haven't tried getting it in a CRAN package yet.